# Azure Dev Ops automation of application configuration present in XML file

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

A few of my application configurations are present in an XML file. These are going to change from environment to environment. I would like to get these values to get replaced during the deployment based on the environment. My variables are present in the Release pipeline variables. I cannot use replace token task because my build is in zip format. I tried using the options present in the deploy task (XML substitutions) - it worked with config and JSON files. Not sure how to make it work with XML files.

your help is appreciated.

Comment: The answer to this depends on several things. Is this a web deploy package for a .NET application? If so, you can use webdeploy with parameters.xml / setparameters.xml to do a deployment-time transform of your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a workaround to replace the values in a zipped XML file.

1,You can use
[Extract Files task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/extract-files?view=azure-devops) to extract the zip file.

2,Then you can use the replace token task to replace the values in the XML file.

3,And then you can add [Archive file task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/archive-files?view=azure-devops) to archive the extracted files. And target this newly archived file in your deployment task.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Using https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/file-transform also works where you target the downloaded zip it is able to transform it the respective XML or JSON and then re-zip it up